# RestKit - map dynamic attributes to key value pair

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am looking to map the following JSON using restkit.

```
"ObjectDetails":
[
  {
    "ObjectName":"Test1",
    "Properties":
    {
      "PropertyName1":1,
      "PropertyName3":2
    }
  },
  {
    "ObjectName":"Test2",
    "Properties":
    {
      "PropertyName1":1,
      "PropertyName2":"asdf"
    }
  },
  {
    "ObjectName":"Test3",
    "Properties":
    {
      "PropertyName1":1,
      "PropertyName6":3423,
      "PropertyName7":"test",
      "PropertyName3":2
    }
  }
]
```

Object

```
@interface ObjectDetail : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectName;
//????
@end
```

Mapping

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ObjectDetail class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"ObjectName":@"objectName"}];

RKResponseDescriptor *rd = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"ObjectDetails" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

My issue is that the 'Properties' has dynamic attributes. I haven't found a way to map properties to anything. Ideally, it would be nice to map Properties to a key/value dictionary. I do need the field name as well as the value.

ie.

```
@interface ObjectDetail : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *properties;
@end
```

Does anyone know a solution for this or have an idea of how to implement it?

UPDATE: Based on @Idali solution, it was very simple. Make sure to upvote their answer if you found this helpful!

Object

```
@interface ObjectDetail : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id *properties;
@end
```

Mapping

```
RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[ObjectDetail class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"ObjectName":@"objectName", @"Properties": @"properties"}];
```

Then just cast it.

```
self.myDictionnay  = (NSDcitionnary*) objectDetail.properties;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can resolve it by setting "properties" attribute as `transformable` type in coredata and declare it as `id` in your ObjectCalss and map it.
If you create ManagedObject subclass it will be as:

`@property (nonatomic, retain) id properties;`

to read content you can cast it:
....
....

`NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    ObjectDetail* objectDetail =[fetchedObjects firstObject];
    self.myDictionnay  = (NSDcitionnary*) objectDetail.properties;
NSArray* keys = [self.myDictionnay allKeys]; //to check for existence of any key`

Comment: It should be typed as a dictionary, not an `id`, it will always be a dictionary...

Comment: When you Create Managed Object Subclass (under Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass..)  all attributes with `transformable ` type will be generated with `id`   :  `@property (nonatomic, retain) id myTransformabl`.  You could change it to NSDictionnary but you will lose any change when you  need to regenerate it again. its never a good approach

Comment: its never a good approach to edit this automatic generated code.  for other needs such adding a methods you have to create a category on this class then add any method.